# I have custom module for add to cart which is not working on PWA Studio

Tags: pwa, pwa-studio, pwa-theme

I have connected PWA Studio with magento, connected working fine but add to cart, create customer is not working due to customization of add to cart and customer create, Please can you suggest me how to make eligible custom modules that can be able to work with PWA Studio?

I will say thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You must also customization into graphql which is related to your customization.

Comment: can you tell me . Should I override GraphQl   api and add custom functionalities which is required?

Comment: Yes you have to override GraphQl API and add custom functionalities which are required.

Comment: Thankyou so much